# How to solve nested transactions problem with iBatis?

Tags: java, transactions, ibatis

Let's suppose I have the following structure in my project (I'm using iBatis as DAO):

```
public class UsersManager {
    public void do {
        mySqlMapClient.startTransaction();
        // my code here
        mySqlMapClient.endTransaction();
        mySqlMapClient.commitTransaction();
    }
}

public class StatsManager {
    public void do {
        mySqlMapClient.startTransaction();
        // my code here
        mySqlMapClient.endTransaction();
        mySqlMapClient.commitTransaction();
    }
}

public class App {
    public void do {
        myUsersManager.do();
        myStatsManager.do(); // here I get an exception, because the transaction is already started
    }
}
```

So, my question is, how can I solve this problem? I have like 150+ transactions in my project, so it's not easy solution to rewrite all biz logic. Is there ay standard approach for situations like this and where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have transaction logic inside DAOs for exactly this reason.

Usually there's a service layer that owns the database connection and the unit of work.  It starts the transaction, calls all the participating DAOs, and cleans up after the transaction is complete.

The Spring framework uses aspects to implement transactional logic.  You'd have interfaces for all those DAOs. Spring would generate a proxy that would handle the transaction declaratively.  Maybe you could use some of those design concepts, even if you don't use Spring.

Or just learn Spring.  It supports iBatis nicely.

Comment: Well, the next thing I will do is learning Spring. However, I already took into account that I have a huge design problem putting my transactions into DAOs.

Comment: Could be worth the refactoring.  Think about how much smaller your code will be if transaction logic is in one place instead of 150 classes.  That's what aspect-oriented programming can do for cross-cutting concerns.  Transactions are one; logging is another.  You might find that putting this into Spring iBatis isn't as difficult as you're making it out to be.

Comment: Maybe not - just a man with an opinion.  You know your own situation best.